# Looking for advice on the best way to show BIRT reports in Drupal

Tags: drupal, birt

On a Drupal app, my goal is to display a page with a couple of CCK or taxonomy drop-down widgets, two Date Popup Calendar widgets and a "fake" submit button. The submit will use ajax to send the info to a PHP page that generates a BIRT report and returns the complete HTML back to the page, which I'll just inject into an empty div. I'd like to keep the controls on the page at all times and just use ajax to keep replacing the div containing my report as the user changes parameters and resubmits.

What's the best way to achieve this? I can handle a decent amount of PHP and JavaScript, but trying to leverage Drupal to create a page and display the controls is proving difficult to understand. Examples I've been reading are either too unrelated or too abstract to be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: So I'm getting further. I've built a module with a custom form that uses AHAH to submit the filters and keep the user on the page. I've got JavaBridge installed to call BIRT reports via PHP, but am getting big nasty errors from BIRT. I'll try to post this all up if I ever get it worked out, as I'm sure I'm not the only person who has ever needed to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No love from masses, but after a few more days of hammering on it, I've got BIRT 2.5 reports to play nicely in Drupal 6.16. You can read the whole story and see code samples here: I've completed integrating this with BIRT via a small custom module. You can read the full story with code samples here: http://nicholaiburton.com/blog/2010/creating-custom-reports-for-drupal